# How would you go about synthesising amino sugars from sugars?

Tags: synthesis, carbohydrates

How would you go about synthesising amino sugars from sugars? e.g. How would you synthesise the compound below from D-glucose?

[image]

Would adding ammonia ($\ce{NH3}$) to it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the anwer is *“Would glucose and ammonia work?”* is: **no, definitely not**. The $\ce{OH}$ group is a poor leaving group, and alcohol + ammonia definitely won't yield an amine. Moreover, in your case, you have many hydroxyl groups and you only want one transformed into an amine, which is tricky.

I don't know how the synthesis of the above compound can be achieved, but I know one way to help you start a literature search: **your expected compound is called an *amino sugar***. In this particular case, it's the **6-amino-*D*-glucose**.